# Using my keyboard overseas

Tags: keyboard, electronics

I have Roland XP-30 which I bought in America, and I am now in a country running on 220V.

The section in the manual on power consumption says `10 W (AC 117 V), 10 W (AC 230 V), 10 W (AC 240 V)` which sounds like it is a dual voltage.

However on the keyboard it self, is says `AC 117V 50/60 hz` which sounds like it can only handle 117V.

How do I know if its safe to plug my keyboard in. Since the wattage is very low, does it hurt to use a small converter meant for low wattage devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go by what is put on the keyboard: the manual might just list the power consumptions for the different various models.  Or it might state the *current* setting and there is a selection switch inside of the case itself.

May depends on whether you have an external power supply (which then might need replacing) or an internal one (which has a higher likelihood of having some switch).

Comment: It has an internal supply...I tried to look for a switch or something like, but couldn't find anything on keyboard, or in the manual.
I know sometimes its hidden behind a sticker, but I couldn't find anything obvious.

Comment: Just called up the local roland shop and they said to go by the keyboard, and I would probably need a converter.

Answer (score 1):

The manual says "On 117V models the AC cable is permanently attached to the unit." That would indicate that there are three different models (117V, 230V and 240V) and that if your power cable is permanently connected, you have the 117V model.

In this case you will need an external transformer to run this on 220V or 240V. 2:1 ratio will be fine. They are typically referred to as "Step down Transformers" and you can easily by them on Amazon etc. You just have to make sure that the power rating of the keyboard doesn't exceed that of the transformer. Since the keyboard only takes 10W that shouldn't be a problem for most transformers. However you need to monitor this if you have more 110V devices that you want to run off the transformer at the same time.